# How do you update a license file that is installed in your Azure deployment?

Tags: azure, licensing

Sitecore licences have an expiry date.

If you've deployed up-to Azure using the wizard in the portal, how can you upload or attach a new licence file to prevent Sitecore returning an Invalid Licence exception?

Answer (score 4):

The license file is stored in the `/site/wwwroot/App_Data` folder on your server.  You can use FTP to upload a new license.xml file.

Comment: How about when auto-scaling kicks in? Would this not pick up the old version as it would pull from the image (not sure if this is the correct term) of the app service?

Comment: According to Azure Support, App Services uses a shared file system so if you make a change to a file, it's automatically shown on all instances. So if you auto-scale out more instances it will have the same exact source code and resource files as the original instance(s).

Comment: You can also edit the same file using the `App Service Editor` - a drag-and-drop web interface to your file system.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a FTPS or Web Deploy client to connect directly to the filesystem on the deployed App Service instance. Open up your `.publishsettings` file with a text editor, and you can see the endpoints to use and the username/passwords.

Ensure you use an FTP client that supports explicit TLS encryption (like WinSCP).

Answer (score 0):

We've had success symlinking the `App_Data` folder to a network share. We've got some batch scripts running at deploy time to accomplish this.